# Validate field based on value of a different field with validator.v2

Tags: rest, validation, go

I have the following (simplified) struct:

```
type newAppRegister struct {
    SomeFlag       *bool    `json:"someflag" validate:"nonnil"`
    ComputeLevel   string   `json:"compute-level" validate:"computelevelvalidator"`
}
```

And `computelevelvalidator` is some validation function.

I want that if SomeFlag is false, then `ComputeLevel` will be required and run his validation function.

A possible solution is to create a static variable, and set it in a custom validation function of SomeFlag, so for example:

```
var someFlag bool

func someFlagValidator(v interface{}, param string) error {
    st := reflect.ValueOf(v)
    if st.Kind() != reflect.Bool {
        return fmt.Errorf("must be bool")
    }
    someFlag = st.Bool()
    return nil
}
```

And then in `computelevelvalidator` it's possible to condition based on his value.

But since this is a REST API, and it may receive plenty of calls per second, I'm not sure if using this static variable will work (I'm worried about race conditions - but I'm not quite sure about it).

I'm using go1.11 and validation package `gopkg.in/validator.v2` (version `gopkg.in/validator.v2 v2.0.0-20190827175613-1a84e0480e5b`).

Comment: Why are you using reflection?

Comment: @Flimzy Copied from the documentation https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/validator.v2#hdr-Custom_validation_functions
This seems like how they wrote the custom validators

Comment: I don't see any reason not to use a type assertion. It'll be a lot more efficient, and easier to read:  `v, ok := v.(bool); if !ok { return fmt.Errorf("must be bool") } someFlag = v; return nil`

Comment: @Flimzy You have a point! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first up: Yes, using this static (global) variable will be a problem for concurrent use/access. It's not the way to go.

If your validation logic is contextual (like you said: if the flag is false, then certain restrictions apply on another field), then implementing a simple `Validate` function is pretty straightforward. I know the package you use supports this type of thing, but an external package will almost always be designed to be fairly generic. At the very least you'll end up performing type assertions. Last I checked, you still need an explicit call for the validation `validator.Validate()`, so why not move that to a method on your type?

```
type newAppRegister struct {} // your type

func (n newAppRegister) Validate() error {
    if err := validator.Validate(n); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    // at this point, we now the flag field isn't nit, because it passed validation
    if !*n.SomeFlag {
        // validate ComputeLevel here
    }
    return nil
}
```

No need for type assertions, let alone reflection. With just these two fields, I'd even argue there's no need for the validator package at all. You can get the same thing done with just standard JSON tags:

```
type Foo struct {
    SomeFlag     *bool   `json:"some_flag,omitempty"`
    ComputeLevel string  `json:"compute_level"`
}

func (f Foo) Validate() error {
    if f.SomeFlag == nil {
        return ErrSomeFlagRequired
    }
    if !*f.SomeFlag {
        // validate ComputeLevel
    }
    return nil
}
```

It's fairly straightforward to use:

```
f := Foo{}
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(payload), &f); err != nil {
    // some shady JSON was submitted
}
if err := f.Validate(); err != nil {
    // JSON was technically valid, but payload made no sense
}
// handle valid request
```

Comment: I couldn't find this kind of validation in the package from a quick read of the docs. Ended up using your suggestion. Thanks!